# Why my binary file is not be able to open?

Tags: c++, opencl, binaryfiles

I am using `OpenCl` programming which includes both `host code` and `device code`.
After compiling the `device code`, a binary file is generated called `kernel.aocx`. In the `host code`, the `binary file` is called to be opened as shown in these lines of codes:

```
size_t length = 0x10000000;
    unsigned char* binary = (unsigned char*)malloc(length);
    FILE* fp = fopen("kernel.aocx", "rb");
     if (fp == NULL) { fputs("File error: file not opened \n", stderr); exit(1); }
    fread(binary, length, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
```

The compiler print out the error message:

```
File error: file not opened
```

I have the `kernel.aocx` file in `device` directory. I compile the host in `bin` directory using `./host` command

Comment: Are you sure that `kernel.aocx` is in the same directory as the current directory for the running process? From your description, it sounds like you should `fopen("../device/kernel.aocx", "rb");` instead

Comment: @TedLyngmodo you mean that the `kernel.aocx` should be in the same directory where I run the code??

Comment: I run the code in `bin directory`and the `kernel.aocx` is in `device directory`

Comment: No, but the process is expecting to find the file in the current directory. You could change directory to `device` and start the program from there instead. `cd device; ../bin/host`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Same problem

Comment: If you haven't changed your code, changing directory to `device` where `kernel.aocx` is and then executing the program from that location works - unless you don't have permission to read the file.

Comment: will try and back to u

Comment: When the program runs, there are two reference registers.
`current working directory` and `.exe path`.
`current working directory` can be obtained with `GetCurrentDirectory()` function and `.exe path` can be obtained with `GetModulePath()`.
The two paths are different and the path referenced when you call `fopen` is `current working directory`.
However, `current working directory` can change during program execution and you should be aware of this.

Comment: @WStar Those are Windows specific functions. I suggest using the standard C++ function [`std::filesystem::current_path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path) instead.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you very much. Its work with me

Comment: @JOJO Great! You're welcome!